# Bottle: run a python script that generates an image and load that image into a web page

Tags: python, bottle

I have python script that scrapes text from a database and creates a word cloud. I'd like to create a bottle-based web page that runs the python script and then displays a word cloud generated by the script.

Thus far I have a python script.py:

```
from bottle import *

@route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
return static_file(filepath,root='C:\wordcloud')

@route('/')
def main():
    picture_name = 'wordcloud.png'
    return template('template.tpl', picture=picture_name)

run(host='localhost',port=8080,debug=True)
```

and a template-file template.tpl:

```
...
<body>
<div class = "container">

%import script
<img src="/static/{{picture}}">

</div>
</body>
...
```

I'm able to generate the word cloud when I enter to localhost:8080 for the first time. However after the first time when I refresh the page, the web page just loads the "old" word cloud (it displays the word cloud, but uses the old image).  Also, I'm sure that there is some better and more convenient way to do all this. Any advices?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not changing (regenerating) the word cloud image anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that web browsers will cache things like images based on their URIs. The usual hack around this is to add a meaningless parameter to the URI, as in `<img src="/static/{{picture}}?v={{version}}">`. In this case you could use something like `int(time.time())` as `{{version}}`.

An alternative solution would be use something like inline SVG to place the "image" right in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However adding a 'version' didn't work, it's still the same old image.

Comment: @jjjayn Hm, sorry to hear that. I'm not sure why it didn't work.